# psycopg2: Could not translate host name to address: Name or service not known

Tags: django, kubernetes, psycopg2

I am attempting to connect to a PostgreSQL DB using psycopg2 and a django app. The pods running the application report the following error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Jul/2023:17:35:05 -0500] "GET /read HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.32.3"  
An error occurred while processing the GET request: could not translate host name "resume-postgresql-primary-hl
" to address: Name or service not known

Internal Server Error: /read/
```

EDIT:
Adding part of views.py responsible:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.db import connection
from django.conf import settings
import psycopg2
import logging

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@csrf_exempt
def read(request):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            host=settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'],
            dbname=settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'],
            user=settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'],
            password=settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']
        )
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM visitor_count;')
            data = cur.fetchall()

        conn.close()

        for item in data:
            response = item[1]
            return JsonResponse({'statusCode': 200, 'data': response})

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("An error occurred while processing the GET request: %s", str(e))
        return JsonResponse({'statusCode': 500, 'message': 'Internal Server Error'}, status=500)
```

From settings.py:

```py
# Database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    }
}
```

The environmental variables are passed to the container with a secret:

Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: backend-secret
  namespace: resume
data:
  host: cmVzdW1lLXBvc3RncmVzcWwtcHJpbWFyeS1obAo= 
  database: REDACTED
  db_username: REDACTED
  db_password: REDACTED
  db_port: NTQzMgo=
  secret_key: REDACTED
```

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: resume-backend
  labels:
    app: resume-backend
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: resume-backend
      labels:
        app: resume-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: resume-backend
        image: rustybridge/resume-backend:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DB_HOST
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: host
        - name: DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: database
        - name: DB_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: db_username
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: db_password
        - name: DB_PORT
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: db_port
        - name: SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: backend-secret
              key: secret_key
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
          name: listen
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: resume-backend
  replicas: 2
```

```
root@resume-backend-677cd68846-9vrm6:/srv/app# env | grep DB_HOST
DB_HOST=resume-postgresql-primary-hl
```

When I run it on localhost, it works (connects to the DB and returns the data)

Nslookup from the pods is also working:

> root@resume-backend-677cd68846-m22h8:/srv/app# nslookup resume-postgresql-primary-hl
> Server:     10.96.0.10
> Address:    10.96.0.10#53
>
> Name:   resume-postgresql-primary-hl.resume.svc.cluster.local
> Address: 10.244.0.114

I can't figure out what is going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  The error message on its own tends to not be enough to diagnose a problem.  The one hint in that error message, as it's written, suggests there might be an extra newline in the host name as the program sees it, but it's hard to tell where it might be coming from.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your comment and explanation. I have edited the post to provide additional information. I tried to use the alternative connection string from the psycopg2 documentation <conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")> but I am getting the same results
It is very strange how it works when I run it from my workstation, but it doesn't when it runs in the pod

Comment: What is setting the environment variable?  If it does happen to contain a newline, the `env | grep` invocation won't show it.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that, thanks! Edited again to provide the templates for the secret and the deployment. I can't thank you enough for your time

Comment: Good news! With your guidance I figured it out! The issue is with how the secret values were encoded (they all contained a newline)
What worked for me was to encode them like this:
`echo -n 'resume-postgresql-primary-hl' | base64 -w0` 
ref. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23404#issuecomment-203404986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with how the secret values were encoded (they all contained a newline)

What worked was to encode them like this:
`echo -n 'resume-postgresql-primary-hl' | base64 -w0`

credit: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23404#issuecomment-203404986